# faulting application winword.exe

Tags: dll

everybody at our company works on the domain but recently some useres have started having trouble with word saying that there is a problem with word and asking them whether they want to send an error report. I've done a bit of research in the event viewer and found this but i have never seen anything like this before.

faulting application winword.exe, version 12.0.6514.5001, stamp 4a8e09fd, faulting modulehpzui43e.dll, version 60.53.644.0, stamp 444d6f51, debug? 0, fault address 0x00113a94

Answer (score 1):

Did someone upgrade the print drivers recently?

hpzui43e.dll is a HP print driver. Try rolling back to an earlier driver, or upgrade to the latest one.
If that doesn't work then the [HP Support forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/) are probably the best place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it was a great help. I'ne now narrowed it down that it was the HP LJp2015 but the dates suggest that it hasnt been updated so could it possibly be a windows update?

Comment: Impossible for me to say. You can easily find this out by opening windows update on a client PC and check the update history there. Drivers does not get automatically updated unless you specifically chose to install them, or if you push them out with WSUS.